# How can i make sure that my windows service is one of the first services that get started on boot? (C/C++)

Tags: windows, winapi, service, windows-services

Is there anyway i can specify the load order of my startup windows service? for example, is there anything like the altitude in minifilters in windows services, so i can make sure my service is the first or one of the first services that get started in windows boot?

I am using the CreateService API to create my service.

If there is no way to specify the load order, then is the load order random?

Note that my service is already launching at startup, i just want to make sure I'm one of the first services that is started.

Comment: You can define the dependencies to other services, that should run, before yours is ready to run.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ but i want to make sure my service is one of the first ones that get started, how can i do that? there has to be a order on which services get started first

Comment: A quick google search and some poor experience removing programs from booting at startup tells me that this is done with the registry , which means either the user manually does it , or you edit the registry during install with the installer .

Comment: @AnAnt but which key should i modify so i can make sure my service starts very early? the keys that are created for each service don't seem to have anything relating to their load order?

Comment: I'm not saying it's a good idea (quite the opposite really), but you could always modify existing services to they all depend on your service.

Comment: @Notoriouss key ? I don't porgram windows and certainly have never made executables, but searching the internet for this migh point you to a guide on *how to create a setup.exe* for Windows, somewhere in which is probably a way to tell the Install Wizard to start at bootup (With or without asking the user) . I know this as an ex user of windows, not as a programmer though

Comment: And why do you need your program to run that early? What is you program doing? What problem is it supposed to solve?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that sounds like some real microsoft behavior

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'll suggest OP to take the user's consent about launching at sartup, as some programs do these days.

Comment: @AnAnt  I am already launching at startup in my program.. i just want to make sure I'm on e of the first services that is started..

Comment: @Notoriouss I'm not sure how such a thing could be done, and presumably I would hope it's not possible/allowed since it sounds like it would open the floodgates for malware. AFAIK, on linux you would modify systemd or the init daemon , not sure how that works on windows , but stongly feel like it could be in the registry. Not aware on these issues though. Wait for a professional windows developer to see this.

Comment: @AnAnt How does that have to anything with malware.. if a malware is already registered as a startup service, i dont think changing its load order gonna be that useful, AV drivers will still get loaded before startup services...

Comment: Services allow for dependencies. If the SCM were to allow clients to specify a load order there would inevitably be a conflict between load order and dependency resolution at some point.

Comment: @IInspectable so its just random? if not, then there must be some sort of order

Comment: If service A depends on service B then the relative order in which A and B are loaded is certainly not random. Now consider a system in which you could specify the order. What should that system do in case you request that A should be loaded before B? With that said it's not immediately obvious which *problem* you are trying to solve.

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/automatically-starting-services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/automatically-starting-services)

Comment: @DanielSęk very interesting, what is the default group? and the first groups seems to be System reserved and EMS, can i just add my user-mode service to any group i want, or it has to be after a certain service for it to work?

Comment: @DanielSęk My service is using file system as well for writing files, so i guess it has to be at least after the filesystem group.. right? but where?

Comment: Which services must depend on your service, please put your service before the service group that depends on it according to your requestment.